# Save Firebase Auth State React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication

i am building an app in react native were users are been authenticated with firebase. Everything works fine but when a user closes the app and re-opens they are required to re-login to the app and this is not what i want for my users.

This is where i check the auth state of my users in `App.js`

```
componentDidMount() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (!user){
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: false,
      
    })
  }else {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
    })
  }
})
```

if `loggedin` returns true i render main app screen else it returns to login screen, and it works but it resets if a user fully exits or app crashes. how do i make it persist